# True and False in Alloy

Tags: alloy

Alloy has plenty of logical connectives like `and` and `or` and `implies`. But I can't find `true` and `false`. Are they missing? At the moment I've been making do with `1=1` and `1=0`, but this is rather hacky (and gives a compiler warning).

<sub>My reason, by the way, for wanting `true` and `false` is that I'm writing something that produces an `.als` file. My top-level `.als` file expects that my auto-generated `.als` file defines a `wellformed` predicate and a `faulty` predicate. Sometimes these predicates are complicated, but sometimes I just want `wellformed[...]` to return `true`, and `faulty[...]` to return `false`. This is why I want `true` and `false` in the Alloy language.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not built in for a good reason: see the FAQ on p137 of Software Abstractions (Daniel Jackson, MIT Press, 2012). The issue in short is that if they were built in, you'd have to be able to declare a relation over the booleans, and then because boolean expressions could evaluate to {} and {T,F}, the connectives would need to be defined over these values, and that seemed like a really bad idea.

Comment: I bought your book to follow up on this comment! (Well, I wanted it for other reasons too.) It's an interesting issue. I still can't quite believe that it's ok to have 2-ary conjunction and disjunction operators, but *not* ok to have 0-ary conjunction and disjunction operators (for that is basically what `true` and `false` are). I suppose the problem comes when you start wanting boolean-valued variables.

Answer (score 3):

Since an empty predicate is true, my favorite implementation of true and false is:

```
pred true {}
pred false { not true }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pred true {no none}
pred false {some none}
```

seems to work; but it would be nice to have these inbuilt.